# Is it possible to execute more than one http request in a queue?

Tags: android, http, networking, queue, httprequest

I want to add more than one HTML requests to a queue. These requests must be executed one by one automatically and I need to handle responses of each request separately. How can I do this?

Comment: Use an asynctask and execute() it like .execute(url1, url2, url3, ... );

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient is not asynchronous and does not support parallel connections. You can use threads each performing separate HttpClient instance.

You might also want to look at ExecutorService: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html